# Errors in TPCircularBuffer - atomic_fetch_add

Tags: c++, ios, swift, atomic

I am trying to integrate TPCircularBuffer into my Swift project. 11.0/xcode 9
I'm getting the following error in TPCircularBuffer.h:

> "No matching function for call to 'atomic_fetch_add'"

The files were dragged and dropped into my project and I've made no changes. I'm wondering if I'm missing a flag or something. Or does anyone know why this isn't working for me?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C++" {
    #include <atomic>
    typedef std::atomic_int atomicInt;
    #define atomicFetchAdd(a,b) std::atomic_fetch_add(a,b)
}
#else
#include <stdatomic.h>
typedef atomic_int atomicInt;
#define atomicFetchAdd(a,b) atomic_fetch_add(a,b)
#endif

static __inline__ __attribute__((always_inline)) void TPCircularBufferConsume(TPCircularBuffer *buffer, uint32_t amount) {
buffer->tail = (buffer->tail + amount) % buffer->length;
    if ( buffer->atomic ) {
        atomicFetchAdd(&buffer->fillCount, -amount);
    } else {
        buffer->fillCount -= amount;
    }
    assert(buffer->fillCount >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental problem is that `atomic_fetch_add` is not available in Swift, so you cannot use it in a `.h` file that is imported to Swift in a bridging header.

You'll need to write a wrapper function in C that calls `atomic_fetch_add`, and change `TPCircularBuffer.h` to use that wrapper function. You can declare the wrapper function in the `.h` file, but you must implement it in a `.c` file so it's not exposed to the Swift compiler.

Comment: That's a great answer.  I wonder if you'd be willing to show an example of what the wrapper function declaration and implementation would look like.